# Advance search in Visual Force

Tags: visualforce, controller, search

I need to implement advance search (smart search) in my VF page.

I will have a search input field, once i start entering values in the field it should query the values in the DB accordingly and display all the available accounts which are starting with the letters.

For Example :

If i type "ad" , the system should pull all the accounts that start with "ad" and should it as a option to choose, like we get in google.

I am not sure what event is should use. anyone has implemented the same? kindly help!

Comment: Use Onkeyup event and use action function to query the result from the database.

Comment: Kindly mark my answer if you could  find its working:)

Comment: @georgethomas you have posted your answer as comments, please post it as answer so that i can vote it.

Answer (score 4):

There's an existing implementation of this that you can use and save you much time in development:

[TypeAhead](https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/visualforce-typeahead)

The OOB version handles Accounts:

```
<c:Typeahead object="Account" />
```

Comment: @AdrianLarson - tx!

Answer (score -1):

Use Onkeyup event and use action function to query the result from the database

Comment: Kinda makes it hard for @georgethomas to post his comment as an answer if you've already done so.